# Wait in C++0x multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm playing around new c++ standard. I write a test to observe behavior of scheduling algorithms and see what's happening with threads. Considering context switch time, I expected **real** waiting time for a specific thread to be a bit more than value specified by `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` function. But surprisingly it's sometimes even less than sleep time! I can't figure out why this happens, or what I'm doing wrong...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void heavy_job()
{
    // here we're doing some kind of time-consuming job..
    int j=0;
    while(j<1000)
    {
        int* a=new int[100];
        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
            a[i] = i;
        delete[] a;
        for(double x=0;x<10000;x+=0.1)
            sqrt(x);
        ++j;
    }
    std::cout << "heavy job finished" << std::endl;
}

void light_job(const std::vector<int>& wait)
{
    struct timeval start, end;
    long utime, seconds, useconds;
    std::cout << std::showpos;
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = wait.begin();
        i!=wait.end();++i)
    {
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(*i));
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
        useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
        utime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0);
        double delay = *i - utime*1000;
        std::cout << "delay: " << delay/1000.0 << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> wait_times;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> unif;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    std::function<unsigned int()> rnd = std::bind(unif, engine);
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i)
        wait_times.push_back(rnd()%100000+1); // random sleep time between 1 and 1 million µs
    std::thread heavy(heavy_job);
    std::thread light(light_job,wait_times);
    light.join();
    heavy.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my Intel Core-i5 machine:

```
.....
delay: +0.713
delay: +0.509
delay: -0.008  // !
delay: -0.043  // !!
delay: +0.409
delay: +0.202
delay: +0.077
delay: -0.027  // ?
delay: +0.108
delay: +0.71
delay: +0.498
delay: +0.239
delay: +0.838
delay: -0.017  // also !
delay: +0.157
```

Comment: Have you considered that your timing code is what is at fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timing code is causing integral truncation.

```
utime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0);
double delay = *i - utime*1000;
```

Suppose your wait time was 888888 microseconds and you sleep for exactly that amount.  `seconds` will be 0 and `useconds` will be `888888`.  After dividing by `1000.0`, you get `888.888`.  Then you add `0*1000`, still yielding `888.888`.  That then gets assigned to a long, leaving you with `888`, and an apparent delay of `888.888 - 888 = 0.888`.

You should update `utime` to actually store microseconds so that you don't get the truncation, and also because the name implies that the unit is in microseconds, just like `useconds`.  Something like:

```
long utime = seconds * 1000000 + useconds;
```

You've also got your delay calculation backwards.  Ignoring the effects of the truncation, it should be:

```
double delay = utime*1000 - *i;
std::cout << "delay: " << delay/1000.0 << std::endl;
```

The way you've got it, all the positive delays you're outputting are actually the result of the truncation, and the negative ones represent actual delays.

Comment: Umm... and after you've mastered the use of the error prone `timeval`, use one of the `std::chrono::clocks` to measure elapsed time instead!  They are easy and when you subtract them you get `chrono::durations` that are not nearly so error prone.  If you're manually converting time units, you're doing it wrong.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm#Clocks